# script hangs due to `exec` on AiX servers with ksh shell

Tags: aix, exec, hang

Below script runs fine on all Servers in my infrastructure.

However, I recently discovered that it fails to complete execution and simply hangs on Aix servers with `ksh` shell.

```
cat myscript.sh
export LOG="./test.log"
echo "Starting"
exec >$LOG 2>&1
echo "Completed"
```

Below is how i have run this script

```
user1@myhost# . /app/myscript.sh
Output: Starting
<hangs here>
```

I want this script to run on on different types on OS like AiX, Solaris and Linux.

Note: This script is placed and executed from a remote server that we use for automation. The script hangs when executed remotely using ssh as well as when executed locally as shown above.

Can you propose a generic solution please?

Comment: Does the output "Completed" appear in `test.log`? The script works as expected on Ubuntu Linux with `bash` and `ksh`, and there is no obvious reason why it shouldn't work on AIX. Can you reproduce the problem with exactly the script shown in your question or is your real script different? If different, show the real script or create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Please [edit] your question to add this information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: You should change line `exec >$LOG 2>&1` into `someactualprogram >$LOG 2>&1`

Comment: @Lorinczy that wouldn't stop the script appearing to hang

Comment: @roaima Here is an example for _myscript.sh_ `export LOG="./test.log"; echo "Starting"; id >$LOG 2>&1; echo "Completed"`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond that's totally different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.` command has included the script contents verbatim into your current shell session. One of the lines redirects *stdout* and *stderr*, so this is applied to your current shell. It hasn't hung; it's just not showing you anything.

Generally, `.` is not how to run a script. Instead, make it executable, add a `#!` line at the top to identify the shell that's to be used to execute it, and call it as `/app/myscript.sh` (without the `.` command)

Comment: post your suggestion it does not print `echo "Competed"`. So the problem persists.

Comment: It does. Just not to the screen, because you have redirected _stdout_ and _stderr_